# Android TextView Overflow

Tags: android, textview, overflow

I am creating sort of an image gallery (with view flipper) wherein each view of viewflipper has an imageview and two textviews below it. What I want is to adjust the width of these textviews accoring to the imageviews width. These imageview and text are added dynamically to viewflipper so cannot adjust width in xml. Also the width of images is different everytime( some portrait, some landscape). Googleing did not help. So here is what I want. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you post your layout file ?

Comment: There's nothing in the layout file except a relative layout. Everything is added dynamically.

Comment: Are you adding `TextView` dynamically? If yes then post that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this, it may help you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="your image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="I am creating sort of an image gallery (with view flipper) wherein each view of viewflipper has an imageview and two textviews below it. " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
tv.setMaxLines(2);
tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

More Documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize